# Composer2 and PSR-4 deprecation notice

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I will be updating to composer 2 soon, everytime I do a `composer dump-autoload` or composer update I am getting the following deprecation notice;

> ```
> Deprecation Notice: Class App\Http\Traits\CheckCabinetTrait located in ./app/Traits/CheckCabinetTrait.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
> Deprecation Notice: Class App\Http\Traits\FollowUpEntryTrait located in ./app/Traits/FollowUpEntryTrait.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
> ```

I have double checked all file names and class names, all of them are matching, I am not sure whats the issue or how should I make it comptabile with PSR-4

CheckCabinetTrait.php

```php
trait CheckCabinetTrait {
    public function checkcabinetnote($value) {
        //function
    }
}
```

FollowUpEntryTrait.php

```php
trait FollowUpEntryTrait {
    public function createfollowupentry($value) {
        //function
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong exactly why do I keep getting this deprecation notice

Comment: how it works when you change the folder name to Trait and namespace with it..?
Normally I think making a Trait folder is a mistake, but it shouldn't be a such huge mistake

Comment: @Svetoslav I havent updated to Composer2 yet, I am afried if i updated those Traits wont work, I have used Laravel command to create that folder , I am not sure why its name is causing the issue.

Comment: Please share more details, like the namespacing of these traits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your class `App\Http\Traits\CheckCabinetTrait` is located in `./app/Traits/CheckCabinetTrait.php` and not in `./app/Http/Traits/CheckCabinetTrait.php` (note the `Http` folder).
Try to move the `Traits` folder in the Http folder as well as the namespaces of the files inside and run `composer dump`
The namespace should correspond to the folder structure
This should solve your warning